# How to resolve No bean named 'xxx' available?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, javabeans, spring-boot-test

The bean dataSource is not created below. Due to this reason there is a problem in creating entityManagerFactory bean. My question is why the bean dataSource is not created? Is the reason behind the bean not created being connection problem with the H2 in memeory database? What could be the reason? Do I need to add anything in the classpath?

```
@TestConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("localtest")
@TestPropertySource( locations = "classpath:application-localtest.properties")
public class H2Test {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("org.h2.Driver")
    private String dbUrl;

    @Value("jdbc:h2:mem:test")
    private String dbDriverClass;
    @Value("sa")
    private String dbUser;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    @Profile("localtest")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean

    public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception{

        System.out.println("___ DataSource construction started ___");

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClass);
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUser);
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        ResourceDatabasePopulator rdp = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        rdp.setScripts(new ClassPathResource("/test/data/Create_Tables.sql"));

        rdp.execute(dataSource);
        return dataSource;

    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{
                "xx.xxx.xxxx"});
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }
```

The error as shown in the log is -

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in x.xx.xx.xx.xxx.H2Test: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' available

I defined everything in the application-localtest.properties to create the connection. It looks like -

```
spring.profiles.active=localtest
spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
h2.tcp.enabled=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Where could be the problem? Where should I focus exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Remove @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation from your dataSource() method.